# Find k so that polynomial division has remainder 0

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

> Find $k$ so that $x^3-kx^2+3x+7k$ has remainder $0$ when divided by $x+2$.

How do I approach this problem? I know how to do polynomial long division and synthetic division, but I don't know how to apply it in this equation.

Comment: You know the following:

$$
x^3 - kx^2 + 3x + 7k = (x + 2)(ax^2 + bx + c)
$$

Just do the multiplication and find $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Holy loadofanswers

Comment: Can you give more detail about "I don't know how to apply it"? e.g. are you able to perform polynomial long division here to obtain a remainder?

Comment: Yes I know long and synthetic division.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Hint:

Let $F(x)=x^3-kx^2+3x+7k$. Then $F(-2)=0$

Comment: Best answer!!!!

Comment: I chose this answer because this question is short and simple, and also gives a reason why substituting -2 for x would be the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Question is same as asking when will $x=-2$ be a root of the polynomial. Evaluate your polynomial at $x=-2$ to see for what value of $k$ the expression will vanish.

Comment: Good answer, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Divide your polynomial $x^3-kx^2+3x+7k$ by $x+2$ like usual.

When you do, you find that the numerator of the remainder term becomes $7k+2(2k-1)$ (by my quick calculation). Then, we desire that the remainder is $0$, so really the problem is asking us to solve $7k+2(2k-1)=0$ for a suitable k.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You know the following:

$$
x^3 - kx^2 + 3x + 7k = (x + 2)(ax^2 + bx + c)
$$

Just do the multiplication and find $a$, $b$, and $c$.

$$
(x + 2)(ax^2 + bx + c) = ax^3 + (2a + b)x^2 + (c + 2b)x + 2c
$$

Now we set each coefficient equal:

$$
a = 1 \\
2a + b = -k \rightarrow b = -k - 2\\
c + 2b = 3 \rightarrow c = 3 - 2(-k - 2) \\
2c = 7k \rightarrow 2(3 - 2(-k - 2) = 7k
$$

Solving the last equation gives:

$$
6 + 4k + 8 = 7k \rightarrow 14 = 3k \rightarrow k = \frac{14}{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your polynomial $p(x)$. By the division theorem, you know you $p(x)=(x+2)q(x)+r(x)$, where $q(x)$ is the quotient and $r(x)$ is the remainder term (with degree two or less, why?).

Then what happens to $p(x)=(x+2)q(x)+r(x)$ when you let $x=-2$?

Comment: Good answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since the remainder is $0$, it implies $(x+2)$ is a factor of $x^3-kx^2+3x+7k$

i.e., $x^3-kx^2+3x+7k = g(x)(x+2)$

This is valid for all real values of x. Therefore, substituting $x=-2$ in the above equation, we get:

$(-2)^3-k(-2)^2+3(-2)+7k = 0$

$\implies 3k -14 = 0$

Hence, $k = \frac{14}{3}$